# Linq-to-SQL - how to make a data entity that is not attached to the database

Tags: linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a database that stores `Fruit` and `FruitBasket`s, and it's already populated with plenty of each.  In my code I'm using Linq-to-Sql so that I can treat the rows of the database as instances of the OO classes `Fruit` and `FruitBasket`.  Let's say that I want to create a temporary `FruitBasket` in code, process with it, but I *do not want the `FruitBasket` to be persisted to the database*.  How do I achieve this using Linq-to-Sql?

The default I've found in Linq-to-Sql is that if I create a new, empty `FruitBasket` and add a `Fruit` to it that I had retrieved from the database, then the new `FruitBasket` will be automatically inserted to the data base upon my call to `dataContext.SubmitChanges()` (whether or not I have called `insertUponSubmit()`).  Usually this is the right thing , but sometimes I want to be able to create a new  `FruitBasket` without having it automatically inserted into the DB.  Ideas?  Best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `DataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;` then it shout prevent this.  You need to make sure you set it before querying the data context.

Comment: Ok... that sounds hopeful, but I need more details.  Let's say I get a bunch of `Fruit` from the db and I want to make a temporary `FruitBasket`.  Can I now turn off the object tracking, or is it already too late for that?

Comment: Yes it is already too late for that, if you try to set the property after you have retreived the fruit it will throw an exception.  You need to set it before you retreive any data from the data context.  Hmm reading the info further, you also cannot call SubmitChanges if it is set to false so it might not be of use to you.